# ORACLE conditionally select multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Having such table:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp
    (manager varchar(14), sub varchar(14))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss', 'john')
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss', 'eric')
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss', 'anna')
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss1', 'boss')
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss1', 'kris')
    INTO Emp (manager, sub)
         VALUES ('boss1', 'dave')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

and given a name of an employee (sub) I want to have returned names as follows:

- if the employee is a manager - get himself and his team
- if the employee is not a manger - get his manager and his team

This one works only if the emplyee is a manager:

```
SELECT sub FROM Emp
WHERE manager = 'boss' OR sub ='boss'
;
```

So basically if the given employee is 'john' or 'boss' the data should be like this:

```
john
eric
anna
boss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select manager from emp where sub in (:name) and manager in (select sub from emp) 
 union
select sub from emp where manager in (select manager from emp where sub=:name and sub=manager) 
 union 
select sub from emp where manager in (select :name from emp )
 union
select sub from emp where manager in (select manager from emp where sub=:name and manager in (select sub from emp))
 union
select :name from dual;
```

Here name is bind variable. I tried with both John and Boss. It worked for me. It gave me data as you expected.

Comment: It works for 'john' but for 'boss' is returning also boss1 and his subordinates. Here is a fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faa63/8)

Comment: Updated the query

Comment: Thank you @Shaili. This one works fine until we add another level of dependence, eg.:
` INSERT INTO Emp (manager, sub)
   VALUES ('boss2', 'boss1')`

Comment: Let me try with this too and get back to you

Comment: I have again updated the query @Mark. Hope it may help. Please check and confirm whether it suits your requirement or not.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Get all manager team and add manager to them:

```
with man as (
 select manager as sub from emp where sub = 'john'
 )
select Emp.sub from Emp,man where manager = man.sub    
union all
select sub from man
```

If you identify boss as manager value not 'boss', you can get team for boss/sub

```
with man as (
 select manager as sub from emp where sub = 'john'
 )
select Emp.sub from Emp,man where manager = decode(Emp.manager,'boss',man.sub, Emp.sub)    
union all
select sub from man
```

**EDIT** SQL Without alias

```
with man as (
 select manager from emp where sub = 'john'
 )
select Emp.sub from Emp,man where manager = decode(Emp.manager,'boss',man.manager, Emp.sub)    
union all
select manager from man
```

**EDIT** remove superior's team:

```
with man as (
 select manager,sub from emp where sub = 'john'
 )
select Emp.sub from Emp,man where Emp.manager = decode(Emp.manager,'boss',Emp.manager, Emp.sub)    
union all
select manager from man where   sub <>'boss'
union all
select sub from man where   manager <>'boss'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I wanted. For 'boss' it returns boss1's team - not his one
[fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faa63/3)

Comment: @Mark how do you identify boss? if it's `manager != 'boss'`? updated my answer with such solution

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. 
But in ma real DB (Oracle 12c) it complains: ORA-00904 -  "SUB" invalid identifier. I think we are not allowed use column alias in a where clause. Do you is there any workaround ?

Comment: for the 'boss' stil returns his superior's team
 [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faa63/20)